# OSX and Windows 7 partition issues on external hard drive

Tags: macos, partitioning

After using Windows disk utility to format empty space (create a Windows partition) on an HFS-formated external hard drive, the original partition that should have remained unchanged is no longer visible in OSX.  OSX disk utility shows it as fat32 format, but files are not accessible.  The Windows side still shows it as HFS and all files are accessible.  How do I get the OSX side to re-access this partition.

*Is there a way re-designate it as HFS format without actually reformatting/erasing all of the contents?*

Answer (score 0):

Run diskpart under Windows, select the HFS partition and enter `set id=af`.